# C++ Opengl transforming a glm::vec4 with a glm::mat4

Tags: opengl, c++, glm

Its easy enough doing it on the gpu via GLSL, but how would I do this in c++? When I try it gives me an error telling me I cant cast a glm::mat4 to float, Which makes sense, but how should I do it?

EDIT

A little code example of my failed attempt:

```
glm::vec4 Off = glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
Off *= Util::createTransform(offset); // Util::createTransform(...) Creates a glm::mat4

for (int i = 0; i < Tvertex.size(); i++) {
    Tvertex[i] += glm::vec3(Off.x, Off.y, Off.z);
}
```

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574125/multiplying-a-matrix-and-a-vector-in-glm-opengl) is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because there is no `operator*=` for `vec4` that takes a matrix as a parameter. It then tries to convert the matrix to a float, but just can't.

To work around this, you should try to not use the `operator*=` and write it all in the long form:

```
Off = Off * Util::createTransform(offset);
```

Also, as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574125/multiplying-a-matrix-and-a-vector-in-glm-opengl) in the comments to the OP, what you need is probably this:

```
Off = Util::createTransform(offset) * Off;
```